# Reselect with $_POST after submit

Tags: php, select, post, drop-down-menu

I just want to re-select chosen selections after submit a form like..
Here is what's wrong, I have selected first three options
[image]
And after submit it's show selected only the last one, i want to see all three selected.

Here is my code

```
<select multiple name="prod_opt_id[]" class="focusSelect">
<?php
    // if (isset($_GET['prod_atr_id'])){
    //  echo "<option selected value=".$_GET['prod_atr_id'].">Selected</option>";
    // }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products_options`";
    $connect = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
    while (($item = mysqli_fetch_array($connect))) {
        if ($_POST['prod_opt_id']) {
            foreach ($_POST['prod_opt_id'] as $optiun_selct) {
                if ($item['prod_opt_id'] == $optiun_selct) {
                    $slctd = "selected";
                } else {
                    $slctd = "";
                }
            }
            echo "<option ".$slctd." value=".$item['prod_opt_id'].">".$item['prod_opt_name']."</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value=".$item['prod_opt_id'].">".$item['prod_opt_name']."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

If you need to see what i use from DB
[image]

Comment: You're selecting something `WHERE 'prod_opt_id'`, but you don't specify what that value should be...?

Comment: That's the DB i just select from db my options, can be over 100.

Comment: you would use the post\get variable to tell the php to echo the html to mark an item as selected

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is missing a condition. Shouldn't it be `WHERE prod_opt_id = $something`?

Comment: @Popnoodles Then he should just leave out `WHERE prod_opt_id`.

Comment: No no, is fine like that, i will delete where UPDATED

Comment: Yes it's using post method.

Comment: Show us the form HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `foreach` loop will set `$slctd = "selected"` when it finds a matching item, but then set it back to `""` on the next iteration that doesn't match. So it actually just tests whether the item matches the last entry in `$_POST['prod_option_id']`, not any entry. Replace the loop with:
UPDATED

```
if (in_array($item['prod_opt_id'], $_POST['prod_opt_id'])) {
    $slctd = "selected";
} else {
    $slctd = "";
}
```